# Excel formula to check if any part of B1 is also in A1 then print true

Tags: excel

Suppose I have the 2 cell as below

```
A1: Hello World
B1: orl
```

How can I use a formula to check if any part of B1 is also in A1 then print true?

The formula may look like
`if any part of B1 is also in A1 then print true`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making my question more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,A1))
```

will print out TRUE if A1 contains B1, or FALSE if it doesn't

Comment: note that `FIND` is case-sensitive while `SEARCH` is not (and could be used here too). Good answer anyway :)

Comment: @Tim : Just curious, what if I want to print Found and Not Found instead of TRUE & FALSE.

Comment: @FahimParkar You can layer an extra IF around the formula, and then put your print values in the true/false clauses:`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,A1)),"found","not found")`

Comment: @Tim : ok, I was trying `=IF(FIND(B1,A1),"Found","Not Found")`.. Any reason why I was not getting Not Found?? I was getting `#VALUE!` for FALSE :(

Comment: @FahimParkar : The find function returns either a character number if the match is found, or a #VALUE error if it is not found. IF() wants to see either TRUE or FALSE in the first operator. Because your case passes an error to IF, it doesn't know what to do and just propagates the error to the output, which is why you see the error instead of "Not found". The ISNUMBER() coerces numbers to true, and non-numbers (i.e. an error) to FALSE.